# Cannot 301 Redirect Addon Domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

.

**I have the current setup:**

```
primarysite.com/addondomain1.net
primarysite.com/addondomain2.net
primarysite.com/addondomain3.net
```

.

**Here is what I want to accomplish:**

I would like anyone (or spiders) who try to access `primarysite.com/addondomain1.net` to be served `addondomain1.net` instead.

For example, if someone were to attempt to access `primarysite.com/addondomain1.net/about.php`, they would instead be served `addondomain1.net/about.php`

.

**The Problem:**

I have tried to set the `.htaccess` file for each subdirectory of `primarysite.com` but it just doesn't work correctly. Here is my current settings placed within each addon domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?primarysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ "http://addondomain1.net/" [L,R=301]
```

.

I appreciate your help. I would gladly donate some BTC to the user who can solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?primarysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^addondomain1\.net(.*)$ http://addondomain1.net$1 [L,R=301]
```

you'll need to do that for each of your add-ons.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the really quick response. When using those rules, visiting `primarysite.com/addondomain1.net` brings up the `addondomain1.net` content (specifically, the custom 404 error for that site). The URL does not change.

Answer (score 0):

You can place this rule in each sub-directory:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?primarysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://addondomain1.net/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for responding. Using those rules, `addondomain1.net` gives me a "Page Cannot be Displayed" message. Visiting `primarysite.com/addondomain1.net` pulls up the website partially (as if much of the styling had been removed)

Comment: Have you placed this rule in `/addondomain1.net/.htaccess`? If yes then isn't `http://primarysite.com/addondomain1.net` redirecting to `http://addondomain1.net` in your browser?

Comment: Yes, that is where I placed the rule. No, unfortunately it didn't redirect. Here's is a screen cap: [Web Browser](http://s8.postimg.org/pf6rlxfcl/no_styling.png)

Thanks for continuing to help

Comment: I need full details. Try answer each and every question I ask. Q0. What URL are you entering in your browser? Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess? Q4. Did you make sure that `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` are enabled?

Comment: **Q0**: `http://primarysite.com/addondomain1.net` and `http://addondomain1.net`

**Q1**: `primarysite.com` has its own `.htaccess`, however each addon domain has one single `.htaccess`

**Q2**: No, Wordpress added some code. However, the other addon domains aren't Wordpress (and have no other code) and experience the same quirks when using the rules you suggested.

**Q3**: `addondomain1.net/.htaccess`

**Q4**: I'll have to check as I'm not sure. I do know that making changes to the .htaccess files do change how the addon domains behave.

Comment: What is your Apache version? Also let's choose a domain where WP isn't installed. If `/addondomain2.net/.htaccess` is't there then create it and enter this URL in browser `http://primarysite.com/addondomain2.net/foobar`